# SQL query to make a table instead of view

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following definition for a view in AQT(Advanced Query Tool), and I want to convert it to a table instead. How do i do that?

**View definition**

```
SELECT TIDSPUNKT,
       QUEUE,
       ANTAL_KALD,
       ANTAL_BESVARET,
       CALLBACK,
       TABTE_KALD,
       BESVARET_25_SEK,
       GNS_VENT,
       INTERN_KALD 
FROM   KS_DRIFT.V_CTIR_SEAGATE_KS_SPECIFIC 
where  TIDSPUNKT>= '2018-04-02'
UNION ALL
SELECT TIDSPUNKT,
       QUEUE,
       ANTAL_KALD,
       ANTAL_BESVARET,
       CALLBACK,
       TABTE_KALD,
       BESVARET_25_SEK,
       GNS_VENT,
       INTERN_KALD 
FROM   PERO_NKM_KØ_OVERSIGT 
where  TIDSPUNKT between trunc(sysdate-756) and '2018-04-01'
```

Comment: What's wrong with a view? Usually you shouldn't store same data twice.

Comment: I need to do a Delete operation on soem of the data, which is not possible on the view.

Comment: You have two tables, and want to copy some of the data from those to tables to another table, where you delete it?

Comment: You could write an INSTEAD OF trigger over the view which executes the delete statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use insert into select from like below:

First create a table with your desired columns and then execute following

```
Insert into tablename(col1,col2,col2,col4,....)
     SELECT TIDSPUNKT,QUEUE,ANTAL_KALD,ANTAL_BESVARET,CALLBACK,TABTE_KALD,BESVARET_25_SEK,GNS_VENT,INTERN_KALD FROM KS_DRIFT.V_CTIR_SEAGATE_KS_SPECIFIC where TIDSPUNKT>= '2018-04-02'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT TIDSPUNKT,QUEUE,ANTAL_KALD,ANTAL_BESVARET,CALLBACK,TABTE_KALD,BESVARET_25_SEK,GNS_VENT,INTERN_KALD FROM PERO_NKM_KØ_OVERSIGT where TIDSPUNKT between trunc(sysdate-756) and '2018-04-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

`CTAS( CREATE TABLE <table_name> AS )` statement might be used :

```
CREATE TABLE T_PERO_NKM_KØ_OVERSIGT AS
SELECT TIDSPUNKT,
       QUEUE,
       ANTAL_KALD,
       ANTAL_BESVARET,
       CALLBACK,
       TABTE_KALD,
       BESVARET_25_SEK,
       GNS_VENT,
       INTERN_KALD
  FROM KS_DRIFT.V_CTIR_SEAGATE_KS_SPECIFIC
 where TIDSPUNKT >= '2018-04-02'
UNION ALL
SELECT TIDSPUNKT,
       QUEUE,
       ANTAL_KALD,
       ANTAL_BESVARET,
       CALLBACK,
       TABTE_KALD,
       BESVARET_25_SEK,
       GNS_VENT,
       INTERN_KALD
  FROM PERO_NKM_KØ_OVERSIGT
 where TIDSPUNKT between trunc(sysdate - 756) and '2018-04-01';
```